# Setting Content Mode of UIButton Images

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimageview, contentmode

I am developing an application in swift. I have 9 buttons in my storyboard and i set the content mode of the button images in viewDidLoad() function. But it takes a few seconds to set content modes, so my page is opening a little late.
Is there any way to open my page without waiting.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sizeBtn1.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn2.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn3.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn4.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn5.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn6.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn7.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn8.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    sizeBtn9.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

Comment: Can you prove that setting the content mode is what’s causing the delay? Is the problem that you are making the runtime scale down big images?

Comment: Yes matt, it scales down images at runtime

Comment: Why are you putting large images on little buttons (assuming that is actually the case)?

Comment: Okay well that’s the problem. There’s a WWDC 2018 video about exactly this! Do NOT make the runtime scale down images.

Comment: Can you set the content mode property elsewhere such as viewWillAppear or init?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in storyboard :

[image]

It may helps you. Thank you